# WPF Validation refer to other field

Tags: wpf, validation

I am working on validating user input:

```
<Label x:Name="lbl_TMSownerType" Content="Conference Owner Type" />
<mah:SplitButton x:Name="cBox_ownerType/>
<Label x:Name="lbl_proxyUser" Content="Proxy User" />
<TextBox x:Name="txtBox_proxyUser"
Validation.Error="Validation_Error"
Text="{Binding UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, Path=proxyUser,
ValidatesOnDataErrors=true, NotifyOnValidationError=true}"  />
```

Now the validation works well using the below class:

```
public class FormValidation : IDataErrorInfo
{
public string proxyUser { get; set; }
  public string this[string columnName]
  {
    get
    {
    string result = null;
    ConfigFileError error;
    switch (columnName)
    {
      case "proxyUser":
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(proxyUser)) return result;
        error = Settings.Validate proxyUser(proxyUser);
        if (error != null)
          result = error.errorDescription;
         break; 
    }
    return result;
    }
  }
}

private int _errors = 0;
private FormValidation fv = new FormValidation();

private void Confirm_CanExecute(object sender, CanExecuteRoutedEventArgs e)
{
  e.CanExecute = _errors == 0;
  e.Handled = true;
}

private void Confirm_Executed(object sender, ExecutedRoutedEventArgs e)
{
  fv = new FormValidation();
  this.DataContext = fv;
  e.Handled = true;
}
```

Now I only need to validate the value of the txtBox_proxyUser field if the cBox_ownerType is set to "proxy". How can I include this check from the validation class?

Comment: Where do you associate FormValidation with the form?

Comment: It's more usual to implement any validation via the viewmodel which presents all your properties.  That would implement inotifypropertychanged and one of the error notification interfaces.  When you're validating User ( or whatever proxyuser represents ) then you also have the value for ownertype in the same class then.

Comment: @TanveerBadar: I added the association.

Comment: @Andy: Thanks for your feedback. It's my first WPF/XAML form and I tried my best :-) Do you have a easy to follow WPF/XAML reference for your validation approach?

Comment: The approach I use is quite complicated so I don't think you will want to look at that for your first bit of code.  You want a viewmodel (vm) with public properties for your fields you will bind. This vm implements inotifypropertychanged and one of the validation interfaces. In this way the vm has the values for all your fields in it. You can then write code compares property A to property B because they're in the same class.

Comment: My approach includes using a base class which is notified which properties have changes applied from the view. It's given the property name and checks for attribute based failures first. It also has a dictionary of predicates which it applies. This is keyed by property name. A predicate is a way to encapsulate a bool based on an expression and I capture variables out the vm for comparison.

Comment: @Andy I think you should post these as answer, it is almost the same I did for one of my WPF projects and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

For cross property validation my choice will be using INotifyDataErrorInfo implementation.
refer to : https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/19490.wpf-4-5-validating-data-in-using-the-inotifydataerrorinfo-interface.aspx

You can get the properties and values via reflection and write custom validations and can reuse them.

Comment: Thanks. I'll give it a try shortly and feedback